# how to solve warning "The Network Connection Was Lost" in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get employee data by making a request to a server, after getting the data I will use it to update the UI. actually I get the data back from server, but I don't why I got error message

> The Network Connection Was Lost

that error message appears when I am trying to assign the result to a value. here is the code when making a request, basically this is alamofire.

```
// send request to the server to get employee data
let loginEndPoint = EndPoint.login(loginUser: username!, password: password!, registrationID: registrationID!)

NetworkingService.fetchJSONData(endPoint: loginEndPoint, completion: { (result) in
     print("a")
     switch result {
     case .failure(let error) :
         self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
         self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, actionTitle: "Back")
     case .success(let jsonFromServer) :

         let json = jsonFromServer as! JSON
         let validity = json["valid"].intValue

         if validity == 0 {
             print("c")
             guard let messageFromServer = json["message"].string else {return}
             self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
             self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: messageFromServer, actionTitle: "Back")
         } else {
             print("b")
             guard let employeeDataFromServer = json["data"].dictionaryObject else {return}
             self.dataOfEmployee = Employee(dictionary: employeeDataFromServer)
             print(self.dataOfEmployee) <--- the problem is in here

             self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
         }      
     }       
})
```

in debugging area, "a" and "b" was printed, that means there is no problem in internet connection. in fact when I `print(employeeDataFromServer)`, the data from server is available.

but when I assign the result to the property `dataOfEmployee` by making the Employee object first. then when I `print(self.dataOfEmployee)`. I got the error 'The Network Connection Was Lost'.

I really don't understand why this happened. what went wrong in here???

here is the employee struct I use to make the object

```
struct Employee {

    var name : String
    var NIK : Int
    var department : String
    var level : String
    var imagePath : String?
    var company : String
    var superior : Int

    init (dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        print("x")
        name = dictionary["NamaKaryawan"] as! String
        NIK = dictionary["NIK"] as! Int
        department = dictionary["Departmen"] as! String
        level = dictionary["Level"] as! String
        superior = dictionary["Superior"] as! Int
        company = dictionary["Company"] as! String
        imagePath = dictionary["Url"] as? String
        print("z")
    }
}
```

I think there is no problem when making an employee object, since the "x" and "z" are printed.

Comment: That error doesn't seems like having anything to do with JSON parsing, it have to be somewhere else, makes sure you don't duplicate call api or call other api

Comment: i am looking this solution

Answer (score 0):

That's weird and I don't think they are related. Try putting a breakpoint in where you print `dataOfEmployee` and look at the variables window. Can you right click on it and do a Print description ?